# Why the assembly Mono.Cecil wrote is smaller than original?

Tags: mono.cecil

Here is my test code
`AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(@"E:\vd\fishrun_apk\assets\bin\Data\Managed\System.dll");`

`assembly.Write(@"E:\vd\fishrun_apk\assets\bin\Data\Managed\System.dll.new");`

`System.dll.new` and `System.dll` have different size? Could somebody tell me why?

Comment: Run it through ildasm and compared the IL output? Edit: BTW what are you doing calling your assembly `System.dll`?

Comment: @leppie I used `System.dll` for testing.I found this problem when I reweaved Unity dll. I had compared them by `Beyond Compare` and found they had lots of difference.

Comment: System.dll is not a good choice. Try something not in the BCL. If it is a bug, report the issue.

Comment: Yep.I had tried `UnityEngine.dll`.It was same problem.I just sent a google mail to report this bug. @leppie